# convert user input into asterisk like password using while loop in java

Tags: java

Using while loop in java how can i convert user input into asterisk while it is being typed like in password. It is possible and how? Thanks.

```
        System.out.print("Enter password: ");

        while(true)
        {
            password = pal.nextLine();
            password = "*"; 
            System.out.print(password);
        }
```

This is the only idea that i have but it doesn't work

Comment: One variable for the real password, and another variable for the display of asterixes

Comment: you can't do that in the command prompt. you can print x lines so it seems that the screen is cleared, or search for a clearScreen functionality somewhere, and print the right amount of *'es, but that's different.

Comment: @ScaryWombat sure, but then the password will still be visible on the screen.

Comment: @Stultuske Sorry where does it say anything about command line?

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you show me your codes for my problem? please and thanks

Comment: @ScaryWombat pal.nextLine() -> seems to me an instance of Scanner. System.out.print(password); -> haven't seen this printing to a JavaFX UI yet

Comment: @Stultuske I think you are probably right.  I thought that I was missing something.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about displaying asterisks but you could make the password invisible by using the `Console.readPassword` method

```
public class Main {    

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char passwordArray[] = System.console().readPassword("Enter password: ");
     // entered password will be stored in this array        
  }
}
```

Comment: Can while loop do that?

Comment: You mean printing asterisks? Could be, but I don't think there's a direct way to do that, you might have to do some tweaks. Pls have a look into this http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/TDA602/Eraserlab/pwdmasking.html

Comment: @DewormHood why would you need a while loop?

Comment: @Stultuske because I've seen a video that answers my problem and he uses while loop.

Comment: so, you've seen a video of code that does exactly what you need? why not use that code? either way, I think if you try Srt's solution, you'll find you won't need a loop

Comment: And also because in my school our lesson is in while loop. So i'm doing some practice and this problem pop's out into my head. There are some parts of the video that cannot be converted into java.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
     #include<conio.h>
     void main()
     {
         char password[10],ch;
         int i;
         printf("Enter password: ");
         for(i=0;i<8;i++)
         {
             ch=getch();
             password[i]=ch;
             ch='*';
             printf("%c",ch)
         }
This is the code. i think some parts are not able to be converted into java.

Comment: oh I've forgot that he used for loop and not while loop, pardon me, but I've converted that into while loop in turbo c and it works.

Comment: @DewormHood You are using `getch();`  function in `C` which will return the entered character immediately without waiting for the enter key,  Also it does not display the entered character in the output screen. There's no direct alternative for `getch()` in Java